# Where does WebLogic 12.2.1 keep the users/passwords?

Tags: security, credentials, weblogic12c

In WebLogic 12.2.1 console, under Security Realms -> myrealm -> Users and Groups, we can add users and also change the passwords of existing users. Where does WebLogic keep these user names and their passwords? I looked at config.xml and I don't find them.

Comment: Security Authentication providers have the responsibility to handle persistence of these information. Then, its depends on the authentication provider you used to create the user or the group. For instance, the DefaultAuthentication Provider stores this information in the weblogic server's embedded ldap. The SQLAuthenticator stores this information...in a database, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weblogics brings an embedded ldap server by default, which is where it stores the users and passwords. The files are usually in the following folder `$DOMAIN_HOME/servers/AdminServer/data/ldap`

You can find more information about the embedded ldap server for here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24422/ldap.htm